# Search API autocomplete for custom search

Tags: ajax, search

**Rephrased question:**
 
I want to add autocomplete to a form using the Search API autocomplete module.

I have Search API + Search API SOLR running but without Search API Views or Search API Pages. 
The submit function of my form has the following code:

```
<?php
$index = search_api_index_load("node_index");
$query=new SearchApiQuery($index);
$query->condition('type', 'product', '=');
$filter = $query->createFilter('OR');
$filter->condition('field_category', 'book', '=');
$filter->condition('field_category', 'magazine', '=');
$query->filter($filter);
$data=$query->execute();
$results=$data['results'];
print_r($results);
?>
```

I can't find any documentation on how to add autocomplete of the Search API autcomplete module on my form, so any help is welcome.

Comment: *[If the question is about code you wrote, for which you want to write better code, or you want to understand why it doesn't work, show the code you are using, or the part of the code that is relevant for the question. Questions that are substantially about code, where the code is not shown, are possibly closed.](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*

Comment: Ok, I understand. I've rephrased the question. I hope it's clear now.